# onEdit() function to trigger script exporting sheet to PDF. Workaround to trigger from mobile sheet app

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-triggers, mobile

I have got following partly working Google script [code](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/87361)

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() == 'B8') {
    if (/^\w+$/.test(e.value)) {        
      eval(e.value)();
      e.range.clear({ formatOnly: false, contentsOnly: true });
    }
  }
}
```

When changing content of cell B8 to the name of the function it is supposed to run the function.

It works well if I trigger this function:

```
function ClearAll() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet2');  
  sheet.getRange('H3:I').clearContent();
  sheet2.getRange('B5').clearContent();
}
```

But unfortunately it doesn't trigger following [function](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3579#c25):

```
function SheetToPDF() {
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  //DriveApp

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet3');

  var url = ss.getUrl();

  //remove the trailing 'edit' from the url
  url = url.replace(/edit$/,'');

  //additional parameters for exporting the sheet as a pdf
  var url_ext = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' + //export as pdf
  //below parameters are optional...
  '&size=A4' + //paper size
  '&portrait=true' + //orientation, false for landscape
  '&fitw=true' + //fit to width, false for actual size
  '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=true' + //hide optional headers and footers, show page numbers
  '&gridlines=false' + //hide gridlines
  '&fzr=true' + //do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
  '&gid=' + sheet.getSheetId(); //the sheet's Id

  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext, {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
      }
    });

  var setupsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet2');     //gets a list where to look for a filename
  var filename = setupsheet.getRange("B2").getValues();       //gets name of the file from cell B2

  var blob = response.getBlob().setName(filename + '.pdf');

  //from here you should be able to use and manipulate the blob to send and email or create a file per usual.
  //In this example, I save the pdf to drive

  var specified_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("FOLDERID");    //specify folder ID
  specified_folder.createFile(blob);     //saves the PDF to Drive
}
```

I use custom menu to trigger the function but I need to trigger the function from mobile Android app as well. So far from what I know there is only one working solution how to trigger functions from mobile app and that's the `onEdit()` function.

So the question is what I need to do to make the `onEdit` trigger `SheetToPDF` function?

Comment: Might want to read up on [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)...

Answer (score 1):

The simple `onEdit` trigger cannot do things like `DriveApp.getFolderById` because it [runs without authorization](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#restrictions).

You can create an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) that will also run on every edit, but with the same privileges as the user creating it (i.e., you).

Comment: Thanks! Anyway I don´t see a way how to trigger the function on edit of specific cell to a specific value. I have added `function test() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("SheetToPDF")
   .forSpreadsheet(sheet)
   .onEdit() 
   .create();
}` and it results in printing PDF every single time when any edit is done.

Comment: The function will be triggered on every edit; it is then up to you to examine the active range to decide if it meets your criteria. Use the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)