# Add a script trigger to Google Sheet that will work in Android mobile app for merged cells

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script-triggers, android

I'm new here, and I have my first question regarding the following post here:
[Add a script trigger to Google Sheet that will work in Android mobile app](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/87346/add-a-script-trigger-to-google-sheet-that-will-work-in-android-mobile-app)

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() == 'B1') {
    if (/^\w+$/.test(e.value)) {        
      this[e.value]();
      e.range.clear();
    }
  }
}

function insertSomething() { 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(2,3).setValue('inserted something');
}  

function convertSomething() { 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(3,3).setValue('converted something');
}
```

This script worked for me for a non-merged cell range which is 'B1'. I need this script to work for a merged cell range like 'B1:D4'.
I merged all range 'B1:D4' and then I modified the script to run for this range, but the result was always - the merged cells were unmerged and each single cell in the range inherited the data validation of the initial 'B1' cell that I set at the very beginning.

So my question is: how to change the above script so it will work for a range of multiple merged cells like 'B1:D4', not only for a single cell - 'B1'? (in other words: how to make 'B1:D4' to behave like a single cell 'B1' in the above mentioned script). Thank you for help!

P.S. I apologise if this question is breaking the rules of this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example code you copied from *Add a script trigger to Google Sheet that will work in Android mobile app<sup>1</sup>* works for your use case but requires a couple of modifications.

**Cells Unmerging**
This is happening because the script explicitly removes the cell formatting each time it runs<sup>2</sup>.

```
 e.range.clear();    // clears formatting
```

Use one of the following approaches in order to clear "only" the contents:

```
 e.range.clear({contentsOnly: true});
 
 //  or

 e.range.clearContent();
```

**Location of setValue() Target**
The locations the example functions write to are 'D2' and 'D3' which are within your merged range 'B1:D4'.  Hard to test properly as you never see the result ;-)

I suggest moving the setValue() target to locations that are outside the merged range.

Instead of:

```
 sheet.getRange(2,3).setValue('inserted something');

 //  and

 sheet.getRange(2,3).setValue('converted something');
```

I would combine the two into one target, replacing both with a single target 'F2' located outside your merged range:

```
sheet.getRange(2,5).setValue('value');
```

**To Recap**
Based on the sample code you provided, the updated version would be:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() == 'B1') {
    if (/^\w+$/.test(e.value)) {
      
            
      this[e.value]();
        e.range.clearContent();
  // or e.range.clear({contentsOnly: true});
    }
  }
}

function insertSomething() { 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(2,5).setValue('inserted something');

}  

function convertSomething() { 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(2,5).setValue('converted something');
}
```

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>  [Add a script trigger to Google Sheet that will work in Android mobile app](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/87346/add-a-script-trigger-to-google-sheet-that-will-work-in-android-mobile-app)</sub>
<sub><sup>2</sup> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearoptions</sub>